# CodenameOne - change color of checkbox in theme

Tags: checkbox, codenameone

I'm using the 'Blue Flat' theme in a cn1 project, and the checkboxes in a `MultiButton` component (I suppose following the Button text color) are completely white, making them invisible on a white background.  I've tried changing their foreground color in the theme (in the GUI Builder theme tab), I tried replacing the theme files with checkboxes of a darker shade, but nothing seems to affect it.

How can I make the `MultiButton` checkbox a different color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue theme customizes the checkbox image theme constant which you can remove at which case it should derive theme colors:

https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html#_theme_constants

Just select the constants tab in the theme and remove the ones relevant to the checkbox.