# Codename One MultiButton setCheckBox(true) not working

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

Im using codename one 3.5.8 and need to add a checkbox to a multibutton(as the example https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/MultiButton.html) but when adding it to my code ,it seems as though it is being ignored, the checkbox is not adde to my multibutton, this behavior happens on the emulator and also on my test device(android 6.0). is there anything that needs to be apllied additional to setCheckBox(true)

[image]

img2:
[image]
img3:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody is having this same behavior, the problem is because in some themes, the checkbox images make the checkbox invisible,the solution is to delete(or replace) the checkbox related images in the constant tab(on theme editor) like explained here:
[CodenameOne - change color of checkbox in theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796869/codenameone-change-color-of-checkbox-in-theme)

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiButton` itself should become a checkbox and would be rendered based on API conventions. You might need a `revalidate()` if the button is already showing in the UI.

```
Form hi = new Form("Multibutton", BoxLayout.y());

MultiButton component = new MultiButton(); 
component.setTextLine1("Name"); 
component.setTextLine2("Numero de reservacion:"); 
component.setTextLine3("Fecha de reservacion:"); 
component.setTextLine4("Estado:"); 
component.setCheckBox(true); 
hi.addComponent(component);

hi.show();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you , revalidate didnt work for me, any tips? this is my code:
component.setTextLine1(String.valueOf(reservation.getEstablishmentName()));
        component.setTextLine2("Numero de reservacion:"+String.valueOf(reservation.getRequiredSpace()));
        component.setTextLine3("Fecha de reservacion:"+reservation.getFormatedDateRequested("yyyy-mm-dd"));
        component.setTextLine4("Estado:"+reservation.getStatus());
        component.setIcon(reservationImage);
        component.setCheckBox(true);

Comment: How did you create the multibutton? Doesn't it show a check box after it's clicked?

Comment: Thanks for your help, heres my full code:
MultiButton component = new MultiButton();
component.setTextLine1(reservation.getEstablishmentName());
component.setTextLine2("Numero de reservacion:"+String.valueOf(reservation.getRequiredSpace()));
component.setTextLine3("Fecha de reservacion:"+reservation.getFormatedDateRequested("yyyy-mm-dd"));
component.setTextLine4("Estado:"+reservation.getStatus());
component.setCheckBox(true);
this.addComponent(component);

It is beeing added to a Form(sub class of com.codename1.ui.Form). And no, it doesnt show a check box after clicked.

Comment: mmm,really strange  ,any  suggestions?  It simply does not work for me(please see edited  question)

Comment: Make sure your libraries are up to date (Codename One Settings -> Basics -> Update Client Libs button). If this doesn't solve the issue I suggest reviewing the differences between my code and yours closely.

Comment: updated my libraries, and created a brand new app(get started app template) then copied and pasted your code as is, but the behavior is the same(please see  the second image on edited question). Do you think it can be theme related? (im using default theme of the "get started app" template.)

Comment: Also created another new app using "Forms navigation" template , copied and pasted your code, and the behavior is the same, please see third image of edited question.

Comment: I think this will be my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796869/codenameone-change-color-of-checkbox-in-theme